# Elasticsearch: Sorted scroll in python inconsistent

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am a little confused with the results. I have a simple query to get the latest document added (based on sorted created date or timestamp):

```
query = {
            "query": {"match_all": {}},
            "sort": [
                {"created_date":  "desc"}
            ],
            "size": 1
        }
```

When I use `helpers.scan()` abstraction over `Scroll()` API. I get a hit which is different each time (inconsistent). My Elastic cluster is static (no new data points are being added) and the inconsistency in response is strange as I have sorted all entries and asked to return the the first hit (size 1) in my query. What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For future references to people who stumble upon this. The documentation on the ElasticSearch homepage may not clarify doubts here but the python driver has a very good documentation. As per `helpers.scan()`:

> By default scan does not return results in any pre-determined order. To have a standard order in the returned documents (either by score or explicit sort definition) when scrolling, use preserve_order=True. This may be an expensive operation and will negate the performance benefits of using scan

So, for use cases like this, it is better to use `search()` than `scan()`